# synchronous activemq webservice

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, synchronization

I have a webservice (Restful) that send a message through ActiveMQ, and synchronously receive the response by creating a temporary listener in the same request.

The problem is, the listener wait for response of synchronous process , but never die. I need that listener receive response, and immediately stop the listener once is responded the request of webservice.

I have a great problem, because for each request of web services, a listener is created and this is active, producing overhead.

Comment: I am using this example: http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

Answer (score 0):

That code in the link is not production grade - simply an example how to make a "hello world" request reply.

Here is some psuedo code to deal with consuming responses blocking - and closing the consumer afterwards.

```
MessageConsumer responseConsumer = session.createConsumer(tempDest);
Messages response = responseConsumer.receive(waitTimeout);
// TODO handle msg
responseConsumer.close();
```

Temp destinations in JMS are pretty slow anyways. You can instead use JMSCorrelationID and make the replies go to a "regular queue" handled by a single consumer for all replies. That way, you need some thread handling code to hand over the message to the web service thread, but it will be non blocking and very fast.

Comment: Thanks!, I will try with this solution.